# Combining several lists into a single distinct list using linq intersect and equality in c#

Tags: c#, linq, equality

I need to merge several lists into a single combinedDistinct list using linq and intersect. I am ending up with an empty list. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

**Here is my code:**

// Merge all distinct material items

```
List<Material> combinedMaterialList = new List<Material>();

foreach (var project in projects)
{
     combinedMaterialList = combinedMaterialList.Intersect(project.Materials).ToList();
}
```

**Here is the Material class since intersect is going to work based off of Equality:**

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public int ExternalId { get; set; }
public string? Name { get; set; }
public decimal Quantity { get; set; }

public bool Equals(Material m)
{
    if (m is null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Optimization for a common success case.
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, m))
    {
        return true;
    }

    // If run-time types are not exactly the same, return false.
    if (this.GetType() != m.GetType())
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Return true if the fields match.
    // Note that the base class is not invoked because it is
    // System.Object, which defines Equals as reference equality.
    return (ExternalId == m.ExternalId);
}

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(Id, ExternalId, Name, Quantity);
    }
```

Comment: Does your `Material` class implement `IEquatable<Material>`? You'll also have to override `Equals(object)` as well.

Comment: @JeffMercado No it does not. Can you point me to a location with an example on how to fully implement Equality. I had a feeling I was missing a few things. Sorry I am in vscode, normally visual studio IDE would assist me with this.

Comment: `Intersect` will return items which are in *both* lists. You, probably, are looking for `Union`: items which are *at least* in one of the list.

Comment: @JeffMercado Just realized my class isn't implementing IEqualityComparer. I think this is my biggest issue.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Wouldn't union include duplicates?

Comment: Your class does not need to (and probably should not) implement `IEqualityComparer`. An `IEqualityComparer` class would be a *separate* class that you pass in as an argument to the `Intersect` method.

Comment: Since you're implementing comparisons in the class to be compared, you'll want to use `IEquatable<T>`. `IEqualityComparer<T>` is for using a different implementation to compare objects of the desired type. e.g., `StringComparer`

Comment: intersect only returns items in both lists which is not what the comment `// Merge all distinct material items` suggests you are trying to do. seems like you want Union followed by Distinct.

Comment: Union removes duplicate elements

Comment: @JeffMercado Just realized that as well... so I added IEquatable. I am still ending up with an empty list. I should be able to initially intersect an empty list with list that has items and expect the items to become part of it right?

Comment: Got it working! Thank you guys! Combination of missing implementing IEquatable<T> and using union instead of intersect.

Comment: @Blake Rivell: any of `Intersect`, `Union`, `Except` remove duplicates

Answer (score 1):

First of all be sure that you have implemented `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for `Material` class:

```
public class Material: IEquatable<Material> {
  ...
  
  public bool Equals(Material other) {
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
      return true;
    if (other is null)
      return false;

    return ExternalId == other.ExternalId;
  }

  public override bool Equals(object o) => o is Material other && Equals(other);

  // Note, that GetHashCode must not be more restrictive than Equals:
  // If Equals compare ExternalId only, so must do GetHashCode
  public override int GetHashCode() => ExternalId; 
}
```

Having implement `Equals` you should choose one of the methods below:

- `Intersect`: all items which are in *both* lists
- `Union`: all items which are in *at least* one of the lists
- `Except`: all items which are in the first list, but *not* in the second

Duplicates will be remove in *any case*.

For instance:

```
// Since combinedMaterialList is empty,
// Intersect or Except have no meaning here: the result will be 
// an empty list. The only reasonable choice is Union 
List<Material> combinedMaterialList = new List<Material>();

// Combined list contains item from all project.Materials,
// duplicates removed
foreach (var project in projects) {
  combinedMaterialList = combinedMaterialList
    .Union(project.Materials)
    .ToList();
}
```